# PHP working with money from different locales

Tags: php, money-format

I can not use the `money_format` or `NumberFormatter` class.
I gave the users the possibility to define which decimal separator they want to use - a comma or a dot.

```
// , or .
$decimal_separator = getUserDecimalSeparator();
```

Now, the user may introduce into the `input` field the following values:

```
1,200.10
1.500,21
1,50
1.35
1500.10
1900,21
```

What I need is to format those values to insert properly into the database. My field in database is a `double(10,2)`.

In order to handle the values the user inserted I want them to be converted to (always with a dot as decimal separator and without separator of thousands):

```
1200.10
1500.21
1.50
1.35
1500.10
1900.21
```

So I have thought about a function which would help me converting the values.

```
function formatMoneyToDatabase($value, $separator)
{
    $value = str_replace('.', ',', $value); 

    if($separator == ',')
        return number_format($value, 2, '.', '');

    return number_format($value, 2, ',', '');
}
```

But this won't work for several reasons:

1. The value might have two, three or more separators (1.000.000,50 or 1,000,000.50)
2. I need to identify the separator of the value
3. I need to verify if the value has any decimal values

Comment: 1. Remove all the separators with a regex. 2. `number_format()` with the proper separators as specified by your user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**, I believe.

I found a solution in stackoverflow which I can't link to because I lost the link, but the solution is by regex.

```
if(!function_exists('formatMoneyToDatabase'))
{
    function formatMoneyToDatabase($value)
    {
        return preg_replace('/[^\d]/', '', $value) / 100;
    }
}

100,000,000.12 -> 100000000.12
75.000,12      -> 75000.12
50.000.000     -> 50000000
12,000,000     -> 12000000
```

**NOTE**: I have validated the price before in another regex function.

```
return preg_match('/^[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]{2,' . $decimal_places . '}+)?$/', $price);
```